# What does the .N mean in this block of Python code?

Tags: python

I am working through Learn Python the Hard Way and am browsing through some code on Git Hub before moving on. I am just curious what the .N does on the line with "tm.N = 1000" and how it relates to the end of the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random
import pandas.util.testing as tm
tm.N = 1000
df = tm.makeTimeDataFrame()
import string
foo = list(string.letters[:5]) * 200
df['indic'] = list(string.letters[:5]) * 200
random.shuffle(foo)
df['indic2'] = foo
df.boxplot(by=['indic', 'indic2'], fontsize=8, rot=90)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Apparently `tm` is an object with property `N`.

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/util/testing.py

Comment: Thanks everyone for the explanations.

Comment: Lots of people took the time to answer your questions, please mark one as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`N` is a global in the `testing.py` module, that is used all around the module to test arrays and other things. Its default value is 30. E.g.

```
np.arange(N * K).reshape((N, K))
Series(randn(N), index=index)
```

In the code you're posting it have poor usage, because `makeTimeDataFrame` can be feed with a `nper` parameter that end up being substituted by `N` if `nper` is not provided. This is the correct usage, that would not confuse you:

```
df = tm.makeTimeDataFrame(nper=1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous line, `import pandas.util.testing as tm`, imports the module `pandas.util.testing` and, for convenience, gives it the name `tm`.  Thus, `tm` afterwards refers to this module, and so `tm.N` refers to the object named "`N`" (whatever that is) in the module.

Answer (score 1):

Source: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/util/testing.py

N is a variable in the pandas.util.testing library (imported as `tm`). It's used in a few of the functions defined in that library, including the `makeTimeSeries` function called in the `getTimeSeriesData` which is in turn called in the `makeTimeDataFrame` function that you call with `df = tm.makeTimeDataFrame()`

Answer (score 1):

You can get information about `pandas.util.testing.N` from the [docstring](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-docstrings) and the [type()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function:

```
>>> tm.N.__doc__
'int(x[, base]) -> integer\n\nConvert a string or number to an integer, if possible.  A floating point\nargument will be truncated towards zero (this does not include a string\nrepresentation of a floating point number!)  When converting a string, use\nthe optional base.  It is an error to supply a base when converting a\nnon-string.  If base is zero, the proper base is guessed based on the\nstring content.  If the argument is outside the integer range a\nlong object will be returned instead.'
>>> print(tm.N.__doc__)
int(x[, base]) -> integer

Convert a string or number to an integer, if possible.  A floating point
argument will be truncated towards zero (this does not include a string
representation of a floating point number!)  When converting a string, use
the optional base.  It is an error to supply a base when converting a
non-string.  If base is zero, the proper base is guessed based on the
string content.  If the argument is outside the integer range a
long object will be returned instead.
>>> type(tm.N)
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes a timeseries of length 1000.

```
>>> df.head()
Out[7]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-03 -0.734093 -0.843961 -0.879394  0.415565
2000-01-04  0.028562 -1.098165  1.292156  0.512677
2000-01-05  1.135995 -0.864060  1.297646 -0.166932
2000-01-06 -0.738651  0.426662  0.505882 -0.124671
2000-01-07 -1.242401  0.225207  0.053541 -0.234740
>>> len(df)
Out[8]: 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

In pandas in the module pandas.util.testing the N property means TimeSeries 
See [this](http://www.statalgo.com/2011/09/01/pandas-timeseries-and-dataframes-in-python/) reference in the section:

```
We could alternatively have used the unit testing function to create a TimeSeries of length 20:


>>>> pandas.util.testing.N = 20
>>>> ts = pandas.util.testing.makeTimeSeries()
```

Answer (score 1):

.N provides the number of elements in array type. For example, if you use a colormap,
`plt.get_cmap('Pastel1').N` will return `9` because it consists of 9 colors whereas 
`plt.get_cmap('nipy_spectral').N` will return `256`